# Usage of the term 'non-reproducibility'

Tags: word-usage, writing

> Studies on genetic factors of schizophrenia are characterized by high heterogeneity and non-reproducibility.

Is the usage of term 'non-reproducibility' appropriate in the above sentence? Is there any other way to write this?

Comment: Do you mean that the studies are not reproducible?

Comment: yes. Was that sentence wrong?

Comment: Just trying to understand what *wrong* could mean.

Comment: It is appropriate if it is true. "High non-reproducibility" is, by definition, the same as "low reproducibility". Another way of saying it is "high variability".

Comment: I think "heterogeneity" already implies variability.

Comment: *non-reproducable* is the nice way of saying that the original studies were total garbage.

Answer (score 2):

The use of 'non-reproducibility' is perfectly acceptable but the spelling consensus is interesting:

[**Scientific fraud and non-reproducibility**](http://sciencereview.berkeley.edu/scientific-fraud-and-non-reproducibility/)

**[SPM Plan: non reproducibility circumstances and CBO interaction](http://allthingsoracle.com/spm-plan-non-reproducibility-circumstances-and-cbo-interaction/)**

**[Nonreproducibility of "snap-frozen" rectal biopsies for later ...](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22831398)**

Answer (score 1):

I think the term is correct in the context, [non-reproducible](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non-reproducible) :

> that cannot be produced, formed, made, or brought about again or anew in any manner.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Non-reproducibility,%20non-reproducibility&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Non%20-%20reproducibility;,c0;.t1;,non%20-%20reproducibility;,c0)